# fopen returns No such file or directory, file exists

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
FILE* json = fopen("D:\\platformer\\resources\\maps\\test.json", "r");
if (json == 0)
{
    // No such file or directory
    String aa = strerror(errno);
}
```

It always returns `No such file or directory`, but it exists:

[image]

Comment: Do you have permission to read it? Is it opened by another process that is locking it?

Comment: Yes it has permissions to read, and it isn't opened by anyone. I created it with notepad, and tried closing notepad

Comment: Your test should be `if (json == 0)`, or better `if (json == NULL)`. What is `String`? There's no such type in C unless you've defined it yourself. Please show us real code that you've actually compiled and executed.

Comment: I already show the extensions of file, and I created it with Notepad++ so I set up the filename manually

Comment: Is the file deffinetely called test.json, not test.json.txt explorer hides known file types by default. (Use organize -> folder and search options to turn this off).

Comment: What happens if you try `type D:\platformer\resources\maps\test.json` from a command prompt? And why do you have a double backslash after `D:`?

Comment: @KeithThompson This works: http://i.imgur.com/K96JEmF.png the file gets opened in notepad

Comment: @KeithThompson: The double backslash in the string is so that the `fopen()` sees a single backslash.  It might be worth asking whether anything changes with single slashes instead of backslashes — it should make no difference, but ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler one of the edits had put in a quadruple-backslash, then another edit took it out. This code is changing faster than we can read it.

Comment: And just to be sure, set `errno` to 0 before the `fopen` call.

Comment: Here's an obvious question someone should ask: can you `fopen` any other files in that directory? Any other files under `D:`? Any other files at all? How about if you `cd` to the directory and try a version that just does `fopen("test.json")`?

Comment: Try this from a command prompt: `type D:\platformer\resources\maps\test.json`. And try this in a C program: `errno = 0; json = fopen("D:\\platformer\\resources\\maps\\test.json", "r"); printf("json = %p, errno = %d\n", (void*)json, errno);`.

Comment: Use / instead of \\ and see if that helps. It shouldn't, but at the very least, you know your slashes aren't the problem. You might try using a lower level function in `<io.h>` like [_access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy(v=vs.71).aspx) to test for read access, which implies file existence. It should return -1 if you don't have read access or something went wrong. In this case, use `perror(NULL);` to print the string associated with the value of `errno` directly. Also, what compiler are you using? Lastly, have you tried opening the file in binary mode using "rb"?

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown doesn't actually prove that the `fopen` failed. It could have succeeded, and `errno` just had a leftover error from something that happened earlier. You should only look at `errno` after you've found that `json` is null.

Comment: did that, json is null. That is why I used errno and strerror

Answer (score 1):

`json` is non zero for successful open

```
if (json == NULL) // or 0
        printf ("Error opening file: %s\n",strerror(errno));
```

So,

```
//clean errno
errno =  0;
FILE* json = fopen("D:\\platformer\\resources\\maps\\test.json", "r"); 
if (json == 0) <-- Fix 
 {
        String aa = strerror(errno); 
 }
```

Comment: @Pacha clean `errno` first then

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using C++'s classes instead.

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("D:\\platformer\\resources\\maps\\test.json");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    // parsing. now it works.
}
```

Comment: It should have worked using fopen as well. Why didn't it? No idea. In any case, congratulations on solving your problem.

Comment: I know it is really weird. Probably it has something to do with the libs I am using